# Microsoft dynamics 2011 with MSQL transactional replication and CDC

Tags: sql, crm, microsoft-dynamics, transactional

I want to know if anyone has a suggestion of getting data from one database into Dynamics CRM?

We have suggested using CDC and transactional replication.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a myriad of ways this might be done.  The method I use most often is:
1.  Create an custom entity in CRM to store the data
2.  Write a console app that
a.  Queries the source
b.  Cleans inbound data as appropriate
c.  Connects to CRM
d.  Creates, Updates, Deactivates or Deletes entities as required
3.  Logs the activity

The most important steps for me are “Cleans the inbound data”, and “Logs the activity”.  Because I am writing the code I have complete control as to what is written and where.  Using some import utility usually leaves me frustrated sooner or later.  In my experience writing a custom import utility almost always pays off.

Having said that there is plenty of code and some decent third party tools available.  You might look at Scribe.

*Performing Bulk Operations Using Scribe Insight Adapter for Dynamics CRM 2011*
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/08/20/performing-bulk-operations-scribe-insight-adapter-dynamics-crm-2011/

Comment: Yes, this is an old question. However it had 0 answers at the time.